# Error because of row names that matches PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO feed (gamenumber, event-id, desc, datetime) VALUES (:gamenumber, :eventid, :desc, :somedate)");
```

When I run this query I get a error that the syntax near `-id` is wrong, I tried to wrap the event-id in '' but that shows a error near `''event-id'` what else could I do to get rid of the syntax errors?

Comment: You either need to wrap those columns with back ticks (\`) or just _**use underscores**_

Comment: PHP is not involved here. The error is reported by the MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is trying to figure out if it's `event minus id` or `event-id` naming.

I suggest changing name to `event_id`. Also consider adding ` around your column names as `"` will treat it as simple string.